# Jquery - IE error on jquery Line 4618

Tags: jquery

i know, this is a realy popular error.
But my problem is that my script is over 1.500 lines big.

What can i do? .... or ... what are you going to do?

**Thanks in advance!**
Peter

**EDIT:**

```
jQuery.extend({
    style: function( elem, name, value ) {
        // don't set styles on text and comment nodes
        if ( !elem || elem.nodeType === 3 || elem.nodeType === 8 ) {
            return undefined;
        }

        // ignore negative width and height values #1599
        if ( (name === "width" || name === "height") && parseFloat(value) < 0 ) {
            value = undefined;
        }

        var style = elem.style || elem, set = value !== undefined;

        // IE uses filters for opacity
        if ( !jQuery.support.opacity && name === "opacity" ) {
            if ( set ) {
                // IE has trouble with opacity if it does not have layout
                // Force it by setting the zoom level
                style.zoom = 1;

                // Set the alpha filter to set the opacity
                var opacity = parseInt( value, 10 ) + "" === "NaN" ? "" : "alpha(opacity=" + value * 100 + ")";
                var filter = style.filter || jQuery.curCSS( elem, "filter" ) || "";
                style.filter = ralpha.test(filter) ? filter.replace(ralpha, opacity) : opacity;
            }

            return style.filter && style.filter.indexOf("opacity=") >= 0 ?
                (parseFloat( ropacity.exec(style.filter)[1] ) / 100) + "":
                "";
        }

        // Make sure we're using the right name for getting the float value
        if ( rfloat.test( name ) ) {
            name = styleFloat;
        }

        name = name.replace(rdashAlpha, fcamelCase);

        if ( set ) {
            style[ name ] = value; // <<------------------ invalid argument
        }

        return style[ name ];
    },
```

i get this error "invalid argument" when i start the page.

Comment: i'd say closer to 99%! :)   what are you doing when this error is thrown?  what is the actual error?

Comment: @Dutchie ... when i make the hole code public <-- my boss kill me :)

Comment: then you shouldn't be posting the question, because you're not helping the ppl to understand your problem =). BTW when your site is online, then you're code will be public,  won't your boss kill you then :p

Comment: @Avinash ... i know. But my hope was that somebody has a good idea. Can i contain the problem when i alert(); into my script?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this bit of code vs. the line you have:

```
//yours
if ( set ) {
  style[ name ] = value; // <<------------------ invalid argument
}

// swap it out with this...
if ( set ) {
  try{
    style[ name ] = value;
  } catch(ex){
    alert('Caught Exception attempting to set: [' + name + '] to [' + value + ']');
  }
}
```

I can only guess that the name you are trying to use is not one IE will allow.  If this is the case, wrapping it in a try/catch will show you which property. (after that you can either ignore the error (if truly irrelevant) or gracefully set some alternative way.

Comment: Ok, i get this error. "Caught Exception attemting to set [marginLeft] to [-NaNpx]"